# Login textbox style - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiview, authentication

I have a login screen with a username and password textbox. However, I've come across a better way to present my username and password textboxes.

The textboxes seems to be merged. Just like the login screen on Windows Live Messenger iPhone app. 
[image]

Does anyone know how to make this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better You can also use Grouped UITableview, add two UITextfields into the tableview cells as subview. This should be look as same as windows live messenger.

Comment: @prasanna: I understand I have to use a UITableView with Grouped cell style and two custom cells for username and password. How can I make the two custom cells? Thanks.

Comment: Just add 2 UITextfield as subview to the cell.contentview.

Comment: @prasanna: In Interface Builder, will I have to use TableView or TableViewCell? Thanks.

Comment: @k.Honda: Simple way you can add textfield in cellforrowatindexpath. see here for example pastebin.com/3v6nJWP9. i havent used grouped style also. let me know if any queries.

Comment: @prasanna: Thanks. I will try and let you know!

Comment: @prasanna: Hey mate, just wondering on the link. It has `enterUserName` and `enterPassWord`. If I just use that code. It throws errors. How can I reference `enterUserName` and `enterPassWord` in the .h file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is a `UIView` containing 2 text fields. You can have an `UIView`, give it background image and place 2 `UITextFields` on it.

Comment: Will it be better to use `TableView` with custom `TableViewCells`? Thanks.

Comment: Its relative to say which is better. Tableview might be more time consuming, datasource and delegates implementations. At the same time, using table view with custom cells gives exact look of the above image you need. I guess, that is what it is. So yeah, you can go for it.

Comment: @pratikshabishikar: Thanks. I will have a go!

Answer (score 1):

You can take two text boxes with none border style and then you can place a back ground image as you need.. This may be the solution.